# Using a verb as a habitual thing vs Chinese

Tags: translation, grammar, usage, word, verbs

I have noticed perhaps that in English we could say a sentence like ‘you think I sleep?’ And it could be referring to (in a comical way of course) that fact of me not sleeping in general or at all.

If I were to make a primitive translation, I’d probably say

> 你覺得我睡覺（嗎）［哈哈哈］

In my experience, I tend to think this is incorrect, and does not convey the same meaning given above. Certainly, I could add words like ‘in general’ or ‘even’ to clarify, but What is the proper way to express these types of verbs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"you think I sleep?" in Chinese should be "你以為我睡觉吗?"

*以為 imply 'mistakenly presume"*

The other answers and comments already pointed out the fact that everyone sleep. the sentence "you think I sleep?" need a lot of clarification-- (*Why you don't need to sleep? How can you do it?*)

Let's use more logical examples:

"you think I care?" =  "你以為我在乎吗?"

"you think I lie?" = "你以为我撒谎吗？"

"you think I forgot?" = “你以为我忘了吗？”

1. *if you don't like 以為 (thought/ mistakenly presume), you can use 覺得 (think/ feel) or 认为 (consider/ think). But 以為 is the best choice here because this type of short retort imply whatever idea the other person has is wrong.*
2. *吗 can be omitted*

Answer (score 1):

> 你覺得我睡覺（嗎）［哈哈哈］

I think your sentence is fine to express what you intended to mean, but you should be ready for further clarification because normally people do sleep regularly.

To be clearer, you can add 平时. I.e.

> 你以为我平时睡觉吗？哈哈哈

Comment: Well I mention it because someone thought I meant 你覺得我「要」睡覺

Comment: @Shmuel well, yeah, your original sentence can be understood in different ways. That's why I said you should be ready to further clarification. So, try 你以为我平时睡觉吗？ it's clearer.